# Problems with updating many-to-many relationships in Entity Framework 6 (Code First)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a simple table setup

```
User
- Id
- Name

Role
- Id
- Name

UserRole
- UserId
- RoleId
```

Using Fluent I have the following relationship declared

```
this.HasMany(t => t.Roles)
.WithMany(s => s.Users)
.Map(m =>
{
        m.ToTable("UserRole");
        m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
        m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
});
```

When I create a new User with multiple Role it adds them correctly in the Database.
When I Update a User with Role's that don't already exist yet then it is OK.

I am having problems adding the following:

Existing Roles

```
Role A
Role B
Role C
```

I want to remove Role B thus leaving

```
Role A
Role C
```

I have tried a couple of things but I always end up with the "Additional information: Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type '...Role' have the same primary key value." or no deletion occurs at all.

Method 1

I have tried things like creating a method to delete all the Roles first then just adding the incoming Roles but for some reason it's maintaining the tracked changes and still sees the Roles that are deleted.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int userId, User user)
{
    // clear roles
    _userService.ClearRoles(userId);
    _unitOfWork.Save();

    // if I put a break here, I can see the roles being removed from the database


    // update user with new roles
    _userService.Update(id, user)
    _unitOfWork.Save();

}


// _userService.Update

public void Update(int userId, User user)
{
    User existingUser = Find(userId);
    if (existingUser != null)
    {
        existingUser.Roles = user.Roles;
        _userRepository.Update(existingUser);
    }
}

public void ClearRoles(int userId)
{
   User existingUser = GetUser(userId);

   if(existingUser != null)
   {
       existingUser.Roles.ToList().ForEach(f => existingUser.Roles.Remove(f));                
   }
}
```

Method 2

I tried to remove the Role objects but no Roles get deleted, nothing happens

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int userId, User user)
 {
        _userService.Update(id, user)
        _unitOfWork.Save();

 }


// _userService.Update

public void Update(int userId, User user)
{
    User existingUser = Find(userId);

    if (existingUser != null)
    {
        existingUser.Roles.ToList().ForEach(f => existingUser.Roles.Remove(f));
        existingUser.Roles = user.Roles;

        _userRepository.Update(existingUser);
    }
}
```

Any further ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: What is `userModel`, as in `userModel.Roles`? My first guess is that it doesn't have the roles in it that you expect it to.

Comment: sorry that should have read user.Roles.

Comment: What does `_userRepository.Update` do?

Comment: It marks the User entity state as modified, then attaches itself to the DbSet waiting for a commit.

Comment: Is it necessary to do either of those things, since you (presumably) obtained the `existingUser` instance from the DbSet in the first place? I'm wondering if manually setting the state to `Modified` is overwriting the `Deleted` state on the relationship between the `User` and the `Role`s you removed.

Comment: I don't quite get what you are saying. I will need to call the Update to update the User regardless if i've added a new role or deleted a role. All I want to do is delete all the roles, then just re-add the roles but it doesn't seem to work. Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59888/discussion-between-steve-ruble-and-fes).

Answer (score 0):

> Concering the error: "Saving or accepting changes failed because more
>   than one entity of type '' have the same primary key value"...

This often occurs when a dbcontext,  having several **same objects** orginated from a **different db context**, is flushed towards the database.

Example

```
  public void Save(PlcVariable plcVariable)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new XBSDbDataContext())
            {
                plcVariable.PlcVariableMeasure.LineObjects // Plc variable has a selfreference that has a list of lineobject, that already has a line object with id = 1
                var lineobject =  new LineObjectService().GetById(1);//=> this line object is orginated from another Dbcontext.
                plcVariable.LineObjects.Add(lineobject); 
                context.SaveChanges(); // error occurs
                // EF will see the added line object as a different object, because it is coming from another dbcontext, than the same object(equal id's) that is already present.
            }
```

You can try to assure to load object with one dbContext.